# UIImage+Retina4 category not working if used in didMoveToSuperview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uikit, retina-display

I'm using this `UIImage` category to automatically find the correct asset if the app's running on a retina 4 device:
http://www.sourcedrop.net/FY53a14b0127f

It correctly finds the asset with the `-568h@2x` suffix if the `UIImage` is instantiated in a `UIView` subclass's `init` method:

```
-(id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"go_back_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:myButton];
    }
}
```

but if the `UIImage` is instantiated in the class's `didMoveToSuperView` then the category doesn't pick up the asset:

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview{
    if(self.superview != nil){
            [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"otherImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"otherImageHighlighted"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
}
```

If the `UIImage` is created in `didMoveToSuperview` then the normal size asset is shown...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try working with breakpoints in the category code.

I had an issue where an image wasn't picked because I set an image as  @"someImage.png" like

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead of simply "someImage" like so

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Found this was the issue by debugging in the category class and used this one line to fix:

```
//removing png extension, if present
imageNameMutable = (NSMutableString *)[imageNameMutable stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameMutable ofType:@"png"];
```

You might have to do something similar. Best of luck :)